Can't configure sonarqube to be available on https using Apache
I have my sonarqube server running on a remote linux machine on port 9000. I can access the same using http://machine_ip:9000. I have also bought a domain and have tried to configure it to be available on https. So far I can access it using http://domain but not https://domain.
I bought free domain from freedomain.one and it had an option of adding a SSL certificate which I did and copied key and crt file to the remote machine to be used in Apache config files.
My sites-enabled/000-default.conf is:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerName my_domain
Redirect /secure https://my_domain
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ServerName www.my_domain

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
        ServerName www.my_domain

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/temp.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/temp.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/tempca.crt

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog /home/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>

temp.crt temp.key are the keys I got from freedomain.one. I dont really know what DocumentRoot /var/www/html is, I am running sonarqube inside a container.
Can anyone help me here?
